# Linq2Twitter search missing protected tweets

Tags: c#, linq-to-twitter

I'm using Linq2Twitter and want to get all tweets with a certain hashtag from any public tweets and any protected tweet of someone I follow. I have setup my connection using a SingleUserAuthorizer, using my consumer key, secret, access token and access token secret. I am able to get any public tweet, however I'm not getting back any protected tweets from people that I follow.

I have the following setup in a loop to keep fetching more results. I get plenty of public tweets, including from my public test account, but from my protected test account I don't get anything.

```
search = await (twitterCtx.Search.Where(srch => srch.Type == SearchType.Search 
                                                                && srch.Count == 100 
                                                                && srch.Query == "#myHastTag"
                                                                && srch.MaxID == minID
                                                                && srch.ResultType == ResultType.Recent
                                                            )
                                                    .Select(srch => srch))
                                                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

I have tried looping through and getting more results (using `srch.MaxID`) when doing the search, but I can't find my tweet in the results.

If I use the exact same authentication but search for my user that has the protected tweet then I do get the response back:

```
search = await (twitterCtx.Status.Where(t => t.Type == StatusType.User
                                                                && t.UserID == myTwitterUserID
                                                            )
                                                    .Select(t => t))
                                                    .ToListAsync();
```

How can I get protected tweets to be included when searching for results?

Comment: What do you mean by private tweets? DMs?

Comment: @JoeMayo - sorry, I should have written Protected not Private. Someone who has gone into settings in Twitter and ticked "Protect my Tweets". I'm not expecting to get Protected tweets from all users, just people that have allowed me to follow them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read https://support.twitter.com/articles/14016 - I'm guessing that unless the user authorizes my app I'm not going to be able to get their tweets if their account is protected.

**Workaround:**
So far the best I've come up with is to query the users Home Timeline and then filter that by HashTag. If you mix that list with the list of public posts then you should have all of them:

```
using (var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth))
            {
                var tweets =
                await
                (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                 where tweet.Type == StatusType.Home
                 && tweet.TweetMode == TweetMode.Extended
                 select tweet)
                .ToListAsync();

                var filteredTweets = tweets.Where(t => t.Entities.HashTagEntities.Any(h => h.Tag == "GregsTestWall"));

            }
```

Comment: That certainly explains part of the reason for a lack of 3rd party apps.